# How do I make a period or duration of a month in lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

How do I make a period or duration of a month in lubridate?

```
minutes(2) ## period
dminutes(2) ## duration

# Does not work:

months(1) # is from base r
dmonths(1) # does not exist
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**  I just noticed that even though it seems as if `months` is from base R, when `?months`... if I detach lubridate and then run `months(1)` package `lubridate` is loaded... what's up with that?

Comment: I would guess that is not an option in `?quick_durations` since months are not a standard length of time in seconds, but I don't know for sure

Comment: @rawr: And years are a standard length of time in seconds...??? How to make non-quick-durations then?

Comment: From 'as.period' doc, Because the length of months are particularly variable, a period with a months unit can not be coerced from a duration object.

Comment: maybe `lubridate::ddays() * 30.4` or whatever number works for your application? and yes I would say a year is approximately a fixed number of seconds

Comment: along those lines, `lubridate::dyears(1/12)`

Comment: @chinsoon12: Makes sense. I get the year via the days and the day via the second. That does not work always (leap year) but often, while for months it is just too irregular. Fair enough. How do I create a lubridate month period then at least? Am I supposed to use the `months(1)` from base afterall? (see my edit in question as well)

Answer (score 0):

edit: as the commenters clarified, this doesn't return a duration object.

```
library(lubridate) 
months(1)
# [1] "1m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

I think this is what you're looking for. You can find more details on the `lubridate` vignette:https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/vignettes/lubridate.Rmd

Comment: this doesn't return a duration object like the rest of the examples